# Spring-security-core:3.0.3. How to change the /login/authenticate to /auth?

Tags: grails-3.0

How to change the /login/authenticate to /auth?

At the established parameters: 
grails.plugin.springsecurity.useBasicAuth = true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.auth.useForward = true

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question can be found in the [documentation](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/v3/index.html#urlProperties).

It should be possible to set the URL via

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.apf.filterProcessesUrl = "/auth"
```